# Laptop display power off on connecting an external screen (it remains black)

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, multiple-monitors, external-display

On my laptop, when I connect an external screen it remains blank and the laptop display turns off. I cannot configure multi displays if I dont connect a display, neither if I connect it (black screen).

How can I solve this? I can provide whatever information you need.

Comment: Does anything happen when you use the keyboard shortcut (Win + P) for toggling between different display modes? What model of laptop is it?

Comment: What laptop port do you use to connect the external monitor?